# Jest reset mock of a node module

Tags: jestjs, google-cloud-functions

I'm working on the Google Cloud Functions tests.

The files are these:

- `index.ts` which only exports the functions which are also imported there.

```
if (!process.env.FUNCTION_NAME || process.env.FUNCTION_NAME === 'contactSupportByMail') {
  exports.contactSupportByMail = require('./contactSupportByMail');
}
```

- `contactSupportByMail.ts` the function to test.

And the test:

```
describe('Cloud Functions', (): void => {
  let myFunctions;
  let adminInitStub;

  beforeAll((): void => {
    // [START stubAdminInit]
    // If index.js calls admin.initializeApp at the top of the file,
    // we need to stub it out before requiring index.js. This is because the
    // functions will be executed as a part of the require process.
    // Here we stub admin.initializeApp to be a dummy function that doesn't do anything.
    adminInitStub = sinon.stub(admin, 'initializeApp');
    testEnv.mockConfig({
      sendgrid: {
        key: 'apiKey',
      },
      brand: {
        support_email: 'supportEmail',
      },
    });
    // [END stubAdminInit]
  });

  afterAll((): void => {
    // Restore admin.initializeApp() to its original method.
    adminInitStub.restore();
    // Do other cleanup tasks.
    process.env.FUNCTION_NAME = '';
    myFunctions = undefined;
    testEnv.cleanup();
  });

  describe('contactSupportByMail', (): void => {
    // Mocking node_modules library before the require
    jest.mock('@sendgrid/mail', (): { [key: string]: any } => ({
      setApiKey: (): void => { },
      send: (): Promise<any> => Promise.resolve('ok'),
    }));

    // Setting up cloud function name
    process.env.FUNCTION_NAME = 'contactSupportByMail';
    // Importing the index file
    myFunctions = require('../src/index');

    const wrapped = testEnv.wrap(myFunctions.contactSupportByMail);

    it('it should export contactSupportByMail', (): void => {
      const cFunction = require('../src/contactSupportByMail');
      assert.isObject(myFunctions);
      assert.include(myFunctions, { contactSupportByMail: cFunction });
    });

    it('should fully work', async (): Promise<void> => {
      const onCallObjects: [any, ContextOptions] = [
        { mailBody: 'mailBody', to: 'toEmail' },
        { auth: { token: { email: 'userEmail' } } },
      ];

      return assert.deepEqual(await wrapped(...onCallObjects), { ok: true });
    });

    it('not auth', async (): Promise<void> => {
      await expect(wrapped(undefined)).rejects.toThrow('The function must be called while authenticated.');
    });

    it('sendgrid error', async (): Promise<void> => {
      // Mocking node_modules library before the require
      jest.mock('@sendgrid/mail', (): { [key: string]: any } => ({
        setApiKey: (): void => { },
        send: (): Promise<any> => Promise.reject('errorsengrid'),
      }));

      // Importing the index file
      const a = require('../src/index');

      const wrapped_2 = testEnv.wrap(a.contactSupportByMail);

      const onCallObjects: [any, ContextOptions] = [
        { mailBody: 'mailBody', to: 'toEmail' },
        { auth: { token: { email: 'userEmail' } } },
      ];

      await expect(wrapped_2(...onCallObjects)).rejects.toThrow('errorsengrid');
    });
  });
});
```

The problem is provoking the `sendgrid error`. I don't know how to reset the mock of sendgrid's library which is required inside `contactSupportByMail`. After mocking it for the first time, it always returns the `send` function as resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got the solution:

```
afterEach((): void => {
  jest.resetModules();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a note - if using babel-jest, mock calls are hoisted to the top of the transpiled js... doMock allow you to mock in the before functions of a test.

This is one way to mock a module for some tests within a file - and restore it for the others:

```
describe("some tests", () => {
  let subject;

  describe("with mocks", () => {
    beforeAll(() => {
      jest.isolateModules(() => {
        jest.doMock("some-lib", () => ({ someFn: jest.fn() }));
        subject = require('./module-that-imports-some-lib');
      });
    });

    // ... tests when some-lib is mocked
  });

  describe("without mocks - restoring mocked modules", () => {
    beforeAll(() => {
      jest.isolateModules(() => {
        jest.unmock("some-lib");
        subject = require('./module-that-imports-some-lib');
      });
    });

    // ... tests when some-lib is NOT mocked

  });
});
```